# How to get and set image attachment metadata in wordpress?

Tags: image, wordpress, metadata

I have post in WP. This post has attached image as attachment. I set description of this image via dialog (gallery tab) in post edit section.

Now I need WP functions to programmatically get all metadata for this attachment (description,title,caption,...)  and another function to set the same data.

What functions to use ?

Answer (score 2):

use get_children() to retrive atachement for posts.

```
$args = array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'order'=> 'ASC',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'post_status' => null,
'post_type' => 'attachment'
);

$attachments = get_children( $args );
```

a full example here [Get URLs, Captions & Titles for Images Attached to Posts in WordPress](http://somethinginteractive.com/blog/2009/07/23/get-images-captions-titles-for-images-attached-to-posts/)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
    var_dump($src);
} ?>


array
  0 => string 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/DSC00261.JPG' (length=63)
  1 => int 1632
  2 => int 1224
  3 => boolean false
```

The order of the array is allocated as follows.

```
$src[0] => url
$src[1] => width
$src[2] => height
$src[3] => icon
```